# How does $\frac{\partial x^* x}{\partial q}$ simplify to $2 x \frac{\partial x^*}{\partial q}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am reading a particular paper and in it, they have the following derivation for some complex function $x$,

$$\frac{\partial \, x^* x}{\partial \, q} = 2 x \frac{\partial \, x^*}{\partial \, q}$$

where $q$ is just some parameter that $x$ depends on.

I don't understand how this works. **Is this is a general property of how complex conjugates and derivatives work?** Does the function have to have a special property to be true? For what class of functions should this work?

---

In trying to understand this, I got as far as,

$$\frac{\partial \, x^* x}{\partial \, q} = x \frac{\partial \, x^*}{\partial \, q} + x^* \frac{\partial \, x}{\partial \, q}$$

using the product rule of derivatives, **but I don't see how,**

$$x \frac{\partial \, x^*}{\partial \, q} = x^* \frac{\partial \, x}{\partial \, q}$$

to get the result above.

Comment: You're correct.  It is not true that $\bar z=z$ unless $\text{Im}(z)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x= a+ib$, with $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Then $x^*x = a^2+b^2$ and

$$\frac{\partial(x^*x)}{\partial q} = 2a \frac{\partial a}{\partial q}+ 2b \frac{\partial b}{\partial q}. $$

On the other hand,

$$2x \frac{\partial x^*}{\partial q} = 2(a+ib) \left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial q}- i \frac{\partial b}{\partial q}\right)  = 2a\frac{\partial a}{\partial q}+2b \frac{\partial b}{\partial q} -2ai \frac{\partial b}{\partial q}+2ib \frac{\partial a}{\partial q}.$$

So your equality holds if and only if

$$a\frac{\partial b}{\partial q}=b\frac{\partial a}{\partial q}. $$

Comment: Is this a well-known class of complex functions?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but I'm not an expert in complex analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Just write out the components:  $x = a + i b$ and $x^* = a - i b$ and perform all the derivatives, then gather your terms.